# NotSupportedException The entity or complex type cannot constructed in a LINQ to Entity query ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

This is the first time i encountered this error .
can someone help me?

```
        public IEnumerable<APPLICANT> GetApplicant()
    { 
        IEnumerable<APPLICANT> applicantdata = Cache.Get("applicants") as IEnumerable<APPLICANT>;

        IEnumerable<Profile> profiledata = Cache.Get("profiles") as IEnumerable<Profile>;

        if (applicantdata == null)
        {

            var list = (from f in context.APPLICANTs
                        select f.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();
            var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
                                 join app in context.APPLICANTs on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
                                 where list.Contains(app.APPLICANT_ID)
                                 select new APPLICANT());

            applicantdata = applicantList.Where(v => v.APPLICANT_LastName != null && v.APPLICANT_LastName != "" ).OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();

            if (applicantdata.Any())
            {
                Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
            }
        }
```

And im Having Error in this line

```
 applicantdata = applicantList.Where(v => v.APPLICANT_LastName != null && v.APPLICANT_LastName != "" ).OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();
```

Thanks if someone will help

Comment: That's odd, the code seem right, are your sure you copied/pasted the right code that's causing the issue? And why are you testing `APPLICANT_LastName != null` twice? Maybe you posted the wrong code?

Comment: The one i posted is where i get the error . . . i only declare APPLICANT_LastName != null once

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
     join app in context.APPLICANTs on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
     where list.Contains(app.APPLICANT_ID)
     select new APPLICANT());
```

to

```
var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
       join app in context.APPLICANTs on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
       where list.Contains(app.APPLICANT_ID)
       select app);
```

if you create `new APPLICANT()` you have newly created applicants without any data

and also `applicantList.Where(v => v.APPLICANT_LastName != null && v.APPLICANT_LastName != "" )`

can change to

```
applicantList.Where(v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.APPLICANT_LastName))
```